# How to run spring boot maven project on local tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

This is basically my first Spring boot project and im trying to run it on my local tomcat. So that I can use Postman for GET requests using RESTful api.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/shop")
public class ShopController {

    @Autowired
    ShopService shopService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Shop getTestData(@PathVariable String id) {
        return shopService.getShopBasedOnId(id);
    }

}
```

Basically what I'd want to do is run an sh script or intellij configuration to build my maven project and deploy it to my localhost:8080

Comment: To answer how to run it on local tomcat: Just package it as `war` and place it under /webapps/ so that `catalina` will explode it.
If you want your maven to do all the stuff, you need a configuration in pom.xml.

Comment: The answer is "don't". Spring Boot eliminates the need to deal with Tomcat (or equivalent), which was a major headache for Java Web apps for years. The slogan is "Make jar, not war."

Answer (score 1):

The above comments are correct if you have a local instance of Tomcat running.  If you're looking to test, simply run:

```sh
mvn spring-boot:run
```

If you're using the Spring parent pom for dependencies, the plugin is configured.  You'll need a Main function.  Mine typically looks like:

```java
@SpringBootApplication                                                          
@NoArgsConstructor @ToString @Log4j2                                            
public class Launcher extends SpringBootServletInitializer {                                                                                           
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {                   
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Launcher.class);  
                                                                                
        application.run(argv);                                                  
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    @Override                                                                   
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder appli\
cation) {                                                                       
        return application.sources(Launcher.class);                             
    }                                                                           
}
```

Comment: SpringBootServletInitializer is needed to run as traditional webapp (war). Spring boot use embedded tomcat by default. So the comment is not correct. Your answer is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run it in external tomcat to test using postman. You can use boot dash board in spring sts or equivalent in intellij. If you still want to use external tomcat, then you need to package as war instead of embedded jar. Look at his article for converting jar to war [boot war deploy](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy)